# Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode at transfer function

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

I try test function transfer in my contract. I following by [tutorial](http://truffleframework.com/docs/getting_started/javascript-tests).
Full project locate on my [git](https://github.com/poperechnyi1/Test-for-ERC20-Token).
It is my test.js code:

```
var SPT = artifacts.require("StepanToken2");


contract("Testing ERC20 Contract", function(accounts){


    it("should send coin correctly", function() {
        var meta;

        // Get initial balances of first and second account.
        var account_one = accounts[0];
        var account_two = accounts[1];
        console.log("account_two", typeof(account_two));

        var account_one_starting_balance;
        var account_two_starting_balance;
        var account_one_ending_balance;
        var account_two_ending_balance;

        var amount = 10;

        return SPT.deployed(account_one,account_two).then(function(instance) {
          meta = instance;
          return meta.balanceOf.call(account_one);
        }).then(function(balance) {
          account_one_starting_balance = balance.toNumber();
          return meta.balanceOf.call(account_two);
        }).then(function(balance) {
          account_two_starting_balance = balance.toNumber();
          return meta.transfer(account_two, amount, {from: account_one});
        }).then(function() {
          return meta.balanceOf.call(account_one);
        }).then(function(balance) {
          account_one_ending_balance = balance.toNumber();
          return meta.balanceOf.call(account_two);
        }).then(function(balance) {
          account_two_ending_balance = balance.toNumber();

          assert.equal(account_one_ending_balance, account_one_starting_balance - amount, "Amount wasn't correctly taken from the sender");
          assert.equal(account_two_ending_balance, account_two_starting_balance + amount, "Amount wasn't correctly sent to the receiver");
        });
      });    


})
```

It is code of my contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;

import './ERC20.sol';
import './SafeMath.sol';

contract StepanToken2 is SafeMath, ERC20 {


    address public ownerFirst;
    address public ownerSecond;

    string public constant name = "Stepan Token";
    string public constant symbol = "SPT";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 8; 
    uint totalTokens = 100000000000000;
    uint public checkSum = 0;

    //balances for accaunts
    mapping(address => uint) balances;

    //Owner of account approves the transfer of an amount to another account
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;


    function StepanToken2 (address _ownerFirst, address _ownerSecond){
       ownerFirst = _ownerFirst;
       ownerSecond = _ownerSecond;

       balances[ownerFirst] = safeDiv(totalTokens, 3);
       balances[ownerSecond] = safeSub(totalTokens, balances[ownerFirst]);
    //    balances[ownerFirst] -= 10;
       checkSum = safeAdd(balances[ownerFirst], balances[ownerSecond]);

       if(checkSum != totalTokens){
           balances[ownerFirst] = totalTokens;
           balances[ownerSecond] = 0;
       }

    }

    function totalSupply() constant returns (uint256 totalSupply){
         return totalTokens;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance){
         return balances[_owner];
    }


    function transfer(address _to, uint _value)  returns (bool success){
            require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0 && safeAdd(balances[_to], _value) > balances[_to]);
                balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender],_value);
                balances[_to] = safeAdd(balances[_to], _value);
                Transfer(msg.sender,  _to, _value);
                return true;     
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint _value) returns (bool success){
        require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowed[_from][msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0 && safeAdd(balances[_to], _value) > 0);
            balances[_from] = safeSub(balances[_from], _value);
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[_from][msg.sender], _value);
            balances[_to] = safeAdd(balances[_to], _value);
            Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
            return true;
    }


    function approve(address _spender, uint _value)  returns (bool success){
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _spender,  _value);
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(address _owner, address _spender) constant returns (uint256 remaining){
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

}
```

I don`t understand how fix this problem?

[image]

Comment: Can you narrow down to the failing call?

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: Can you simplify your contract to a minimal test that causes the same error?

Comment: Yes.I haven`t error when I try testing simple erc20 contract and function "transfer" complete test successfull but when I try do it for ERC20 token with two owners, which set durring deployment in construcor that test not complete successfull.

Answer (score 0):

> Can you simplify your contract to a minimal test that causes the same error?

I simplify my contract for testing "transfer function" and it don`t work yet.
I try call function transfer in my test for contract which has two owners and I have the same error:

> Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.15;    

import './SafeMath.sol';

contract TransferToken is SafeMath {
    event Transfer(address indexed _from, address indexed _to, uint _value);
    event Approval(address indexed _owner, address indexed _spender, uint _value);

    address public ownerFirst;
    address public ownerSecond;

    string public constant name = "Stepan Token";
    string public constant symbol = "SPT";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 8; 
    uint totalTokens = 100000000000000;
    uint public checkSum = 0;

    //balances for accaunts
    mapping(address => uint) balances;

    //Owner of account approves the transfer of an amount to another account
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;


    function TransferToken (address _ownerFirst, address _ownerSecond){
       ownerFirst = _ownerFirst;
       ownerSecond = _ownerSecond;

       balances[ownerFirst] = safeDiv(totalTokens, 3);
       balances[ownerSecond] = safeSub(totalTokens, balances[ownerFirst]);
    //    balances[ownerFirst] -= 10;
       checkSum = safeAdd(balances[ownerFirst], balances[ownerSecond]);

       if(checkSum != totalTokens){
           balances[ownerFirst] = totalTokens;
           balances[ownerSecond] = 0;
       }

    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) constant returns (uint256 balance){
         return balances[_owner];
    }


    function transfer(address _to, uint _value)  returns (bool success){
            require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value && _value > 0 && safeAdd(balances[_to], _value) > balances[_to]);
                balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender],_value);
                balances[_to] = safeAdd(balances[_to], _value);
                Transfer(msg.sender,  _to, _value);
                return true;     
    }   
}
```

And I have test for it:

```
var TFT = artifacts.require('TransferToken');

contract("Testing Transfer function in token", function(accounts){
    it("Should send coin correctly", function() {
        var meta;

        // Get initial balances of first and second account.
        var account_one = accounts[0];
        var account_two = accounts[1];
        console.log("account_two", typeof(account_two));

        var account_one_starting_balance;
        var account_two_starting_balance;
        var account_one_ending_balance;
        var account_two_ending_balance;

        var amount = 100000000;

        return TFT.deployed(account_one,account_two).then(function(instance) {
          meta = instance;
          return meta.balanceOf.call(account_one);
        }).then(function(balance) {
          account_one_starting_balance = balance.toNumber();
          return meta.balanceOf.call(account_two);
        }).then(function(balance) {
          account_two_starting_balance = balance.toNumber();
          return meta.transfer(account_two, amount, {from: account_one});
        }).then(function() {
          return meta.balanceOf.call(account_one);
        }).then(function(balance) {
          account_one_ending_balance = balance.toNumber();
          return meta.balanceOf.call(account_two);
        }).then(function(balance) {
          account_two_ending_balance = balance.toNumber();

          assert.equal(account_one_ending_balance, account_one_starting_balance - amount, "Amount wasn't correctly taken from the sender");
          assert.equal(account_two_ending_balance, account_two_starting_balance + amount, "Amount wasn't correctly sent to the receiver");
      });
    });
});
```